# Attempting to use defineModel() in vue 3.4 using typescript gives a compilation error "TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'mergeModels'."

Tags: vuejs3, vue-typescript

I am attempting to use defineModel in my application, as `const model = defineModel();` with typescript, but I'm getting a compilation error

```
TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'mergeModels'.
```

I have the following relevant packages:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.16.0",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.0",
"ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
"typescript": "^4",
"vue": "^3.4.0",
"vue-loader": "^17.4.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16"
```

My tsconfig looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "es2022",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node16",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@classes*": ["resources/assets/js/classes*"],
            "@assets*": ["resources/assets*"],
            "@ziggy*": ["vendor/tightenco/ziggy*"],
            "@components*": ["resources/assets/js/components*"]
        },
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/assets/js/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling

Comment: I have same issue. After Reinstalling node_modules (with pnpm) and problem solved.

Comment: Problem not solved for me, what other things do you have in your package.json?

Comment: Other things you can try are [upgrading all required dependencies](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-4#potential-actions-needed), upgrading typescript, and reloading your IDE environment.  It might also be an issue with your TS config, so including that in your question might be helpful.

Comment: @yoduh I added the tsconfig. Restarting IDE didn't help.

Comment: No I haven't @WizardZ. Using current version of vue (3.4.15) too.